# Dynamic jQuery content loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im adding staff members to my CMS but having trouble loading members as i think my code is quite messy. Is it possible to remove "li a.job-desc" & "li a.job-desc1" etc and have one global variable that works for all staff members. Once clicked on each staff member their own description should open and other members close

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zangief007/BSN5u/14/

HTML:

```
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="job-desc1"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="staff1" width="191" height="191"></a></li>
        <li>Jon doe</li>
        <li>09 548 5554</li>
        <li>jon@gmail.com</li>
      </ul>

       <p class="description1">Joe Doe dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, tempora, libero, ipsa maxime facere ullam harum ad iusto laborum minima magni officia provident aut obcaecati quaerat fugiat labore qui aliquam.</p>

       <ul>
           <li><a href="#" class="job-desc2"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="staff1" width="191" height="191"></a></li>
        <li>Jenny Hill</li>
        <li>09 548 5554</li>
        <li>jon@gmail.com</li>

      </ul>

      <p class="description2">Jenny Hill dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, tempora, libero, ipsa maxime facere ullam harum ad iusto laborum minima magni officia provident aut obcaecati quaerat fugiat labore qui aliquam.</p>


         <ul>
             <li><a href="#" class="job-desc3"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="staff1" width="191" height="191"></a></li>
        <li>Peter Small</li>
        <li>09 548 5554</li>
        <li>jon@gmail.com</li>

      </ul>

      <p class="description3">Peter Small dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis, tempora, libero, ipsa maxime facere ullam harum ad iusto laborum minima magni officia provident aut obcaecati quaerat fugiat labore qui aliquam.</p>

  </div>
```

JS:

```
 $( "li a.job-desc" ).click(function() {
          $( "p.description" ).fadeToggle( "slow", "linear" );
});

$( "li a.job-desc1" ).click(function() {
          $( "p.description1" ).fadeToggle( "slow", "linear" );
});

$( "li a.job-desc2" ).click(function() {
              $( "p.description2" ).fadeToggle( "slow", "linear" );
});
</script>
```

Comment: from the coding point of view most classes name should be same, instead we use ID if we have unique elements

Comment: Yes, each member should have its own unique ID. Is it possible to link the image with the description without hard coding?

Comment: you can try using the emp id in the ID field of the html element in the <img> element. Then follow one of the answers below if you want to dynamically want to load the description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS classes are used to group a set of elements. Adding classes like `class1`, `class2` etc for each element does not make sense.

(For accessing particular element, you can use an `id` instead, which will be way faster compared to accessing it using `class`)

In this case, you can give a common class `job-desc` for `<a>` and `description` for `<p>` then you can use the following script to show respective descriptions.

```
$("li a.job-desc").click(function () {
  $(this).closest('ul').next("p.description").fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BSN5u/15/)

If you want to close the other descriptions, you can use the [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible/) selector as follows:

```
 $("li a.job-desc").click(function () {
  var $desc = $(this).closest("ul").next("p.description").fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
  $('p.description:visible').not($desc).hide();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BSN5u/20/)

Comment: I'm, as usual, the last one with answer, but the fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/BSN5u/15/

Comment: In this case it would suffice to use "li a" as the selector. Otherwise, probably the best answer so far.

Comment: Thats great, thankyou. Is it possible to have the description load below all images. So the line of 3 stay at the top? Without touching the HTML?

Comment: @Steve What do you mean by *line of 3*?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BSN5u/16/ not allows to hide the description on clicking to the same block. I haven't actualy got an idea how to fix this yet.

Comment: @TilwinJoy all images and short descriptions ('<ul>') should be at the top of page, and current description is always under them. I also have no idea how to do it yet

Comment: Is it possible to have the <p> tag display under neath each image without them jumping around? Without touching the HTML?

Comment: @Steve I'm still thinking about it, but nothing except trying to do something with `css position` is got to my mind yet

Comment: @Regent in that case, i think it's best to alter the html structure, something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/BSN5u/21/)

Comment: @TilwinJoy but what about something without html impact? :)

Comment: @Regent that is also possible… we can have a dummy `<p>` at the bottom, and change it's content dynamically… I wouldn't suggest unnecessary `DOM` manipulation though. It's always better to create the most suitable `html` structure to avoid `dom` manipulation IMHO

Comment: @Steve, TilwinJoy, well, that's what I ended up with: http://jsfiddle.net/BSN5u/22/. Looks like perversion, but nevertheless...

Comment: Thats awesome. Thankyou. Just on the off chance is it possible to add a selected state. Say Change the colour of the background of the member clicked?

Comment: Actually, didnt quite work. I will probably end up having about 3 rows of 3? Depending on the staff limits? This example only work for 3. And is fixed therefor when user scrolls. The description doesnt move :(

Comment: @Steve As far as i know, the question you asked was for removing multiple handlers, and hiding the previous description. If you're having trouble with something else, please post a different question..

Comment: @Steve what does work only for 3 elements? My last strange thing or answer in whole?

Answer (score 0):

use each iterator

```
$("li a").each(function(index,ele){
  $(this).click (function(){
    $(this).closest("ul").next("p.description").fadeToggle( "slow", "linear" );
  });
});
```

Comment: This seems to open all descriptions, not the corresponding description?

Comment: This also adds separate event handler for each element, which is very bad idea

Comment: this will open the closest ul next descriotions

Answer (score 0):

It gets a little messy when link and description aren't contained within a separate container, but this should fade in the associated description and fade out all other descriptions.

```
$("li a.job-desc").click(function() {
   // first find the description associated with the clicked link
   var description = $(this).closest("ul").nextAll("p.description").first();
   description.siblings("p.description").fadeOut();
   description.fadeIn();
});
```